# Extract struct from NSData in Swift

Tags: ios, pointers, struct, swift, nsdata

I'm making Game Center game.  I send a data packet containing a `struct MovePacket` like this:

```
var packet = MovePacket(packetID: 1, move: myMove)

let dataPacket = NSData(bytes: &packet, length: sizeof(MovePacket))

currentMatch!.sendDataToAllPlayers(dataPacket, withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataMode.Reliable, error: nil)
```

This works like in Objective-C, but I don't understand how to decode the received `NSData` back to my `struct MovePacket`.  This is one of my tries:

```
func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer!) {

    var packet : MovePacket 

    data.getBytes(&packet, length: sizeof(MovePacket)) // getting error here: Address of variable 'packet' taken before it is initialized

    println(packet) //Variable 'packet' used before being initialized

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var packet : MovePacket()`?

Comment: I don't see any dates mentioned in your code.  Did you mean to say “decode it back from **NSData**”?

Comment: @robmayoff I meant data not date. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant “decode it back from **`NSData`**”:

```
func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer!) {
    if data.length == sizeof(MovePacket) {
        let packet = UnsafePointer<MovePacket>(data.bytes).memory
        println(packet)
    } else {
        // error: data size is incorrect
    }
}
```