# Swift structs to NSData and back

Tags: swift, serialization, struct, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I have a struct containing a struct and an `NSObject` that I want to serialize into an `NSData` object:

```
struct Packet {
  var name: String
  var index: Int
  var numberOfPackets: Int
  var data: NSData
}

var thePacket = Packet(name: name, index: i, numberOfPackets: numberOfPackets, data: packetData)
```

How do I best serialize the Packet into an `NSData`, and how do I best deserialize it?

Using

```
var bufferData = NSData(bytes: & thePacket, length: sizeof(Packet))
```

of only gives me the pointers of name and data. I was exploring `NSKeyedArchiver`, but then I'd have to make Packet an object, and I'd prefer to keep it a struct.

Cheers

Nik

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/x43x61x69/Struct-to-NSData-and-Back-Examples

Comment: Unfortunately not, he's got a bug where he's not saving the String! but saving the memory address. As he reads it back and references it, the string is still in memory. But he never actually saves the content of the String!

Comment: What about this method: https://gist.github.com/nubbel/5b0a5cb2bf6a2e353061 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not really getting any feedback, this is the solution I ended up with:

1. Make `encode()` and `decode()` functions for my struct
2. Change `Int` to `Int64` so the `Int` has the same size on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms
3. Have an intermediate struct (ArchivedPacket) that has no String or `Data`, but only `Int64`

Here is my code, I would be very grateful for your feedback, especially  if there are less cumbersome ways to do this:

```
public struct Packet {
    var name: String
    var index: Int64
    var numberOfPackets: Int64
    var data: NSData

    struct ArchivedPacket {
        var index : Int64
        var numberOfPackets : Int64
        var nameLength : Int64
        var dataLength : Int64
    }

    func archive() -> NSData {

        var archivedPacket = ArchivedPacket(index: Int64(self.index), numberOfPackets: Int64(self.numberOfPackets), nameLength: Int64(self.name.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)), dataLength: Int64(self.data.length))

        var metadata = NSData(
            bytes: &archivedPacket,
            length: sizeof(ArchivedPacket)
        )

        let archivedData = NSMutableData(data: metadata)
        archivedData.appendData(name.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        archivedData.appendData(data)

        return archivedData
    }

    func unarchive(data: NSData!) -> Packet {
        var archivedPacket = ArchivedPacket(index: 0, numberOfPackets: 0, nameLength: 0, dataLength: 0)
        let archivedStructLength = sizeof(ArchivedPacket)

        let archivedData = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, archivedStructLength))
        archivedData.getBytes(&archivedPacket)

        let nameRange = NSMakeRange(archivedStructLength, Int(archivedPacket.nameLength))
        let dataRange = NSMakeRange(archivedStructLength + Int(archivedPacket.nameLength), Int(archivedPacket.dataLength))

        let nameData = data.subdataWithRange(nameRange)
        let name = NSString(data: nameData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        let theData = data.subdataWithRange(dataRange)

        let packet = Packet(name: name, index: archivedPacket.index, numberOfPackets: archivedPacket.numberOfPackets, data: theData)

        return packet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 5

If you are on Apple platforms, use `Codable` now. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable).

## Swift 3

This is an unaltered copy-paste from a Playground in Xcode 8.2.1 that works. It is a bit simpler than other answers.

```
import Foundation

enum WhizzoKind {
    case floom
    case bzzz
}

struct Whizzo {
    let name: String
    let num: Int
    let kind:WhizzoKind

    static func archive(w:Whizzo) -> Data {
        var fw = w
        return Data(bytes: &fw, count: MemoryLayout<Whizzo>.stride)
    }

    static func unarchive(d:Data) -> Whizzo {
        guard d.count == MemoryLayout<Whizzo>.stride else {
            fatalError("BOOM!")
        }

        var w:Whizzo?
        d.withUnsafeBytes({(bytes: UnsafePointer<Whizzo>)->Void in
            w = UnsafePointer<Whizzo>(bytes).pointee
        })
        return w!
    }
}

let thing = Whizzo(name:"Bob", num:77, kind:.bzzz)
print("thing = \(thing)")
let dataThing = Whizzo.archive(w: thing)
let convertedThing = Whizzo.unarchive(d: dataThing)
print("convertedThing = \(convertedThing)")
```

### Notes

I couldn't make `archive` and `unarchive` instance methods because  `Data.init(bytes:​count:​)` is mutating on the `bytes` parameter? And `self` isn't mutable, so... This made no sense to me.

The `WhizzoKind` enum is in there because that is something I care about. It's not important for the example. Someone might be paranoid about enums like I am.

I had to cobble this answer together from 4 other SO question/answers:

- [Getting data out of NSData with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317811/getting-data-out-of-nsdata-with-swift)
- [Extract struct from NSData in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305359/extract-struct-from-nsdata-in-swift)
- ['bytes' is unavailable: use withUnsafeBytes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979575/bytes-is-unavailable-use-withunsafebytes-instead)
- [Unsafe bytes in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565415/unsafe-bytes-in-swift-3)

And these docs:
- http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/UnsafePointer/

And meditating on the Swift closure syntax until I wanted to scream.

So thanks to those other SO askers/authors.

### Update

So **this will *not* work across devices**. For example, sending from iPhone 7 to Apple Watch. Because the `stride` is different. The above example is 80 bytes on iPhone 7 Simulator but 40 bytes on Apple Watch Series 2 Simulator.

It looks like the approach (but not syntax) by @niklassaers is still the only one that will work. I'm going to leave this answer here because it might help others with all the new Swift 3 syntax and API changes surrounding this topic.

Our only real hope is this Swift proposal: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md

Comment: This will not even work on the same device, I don't think. It only works by accident in your example because the `name` String is kept in memory. You are not actually serialising the string here.

Comment: @DagÅgren I will look into your claim by doing a different test outside of a Playground and in a full project.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for basic struct objects is ***PropertyListEncoder & PropertyListDecoder***.

This is the sample code;

**Swift 5**

```
struct Packet: Codable {
   var name: String
   var index: Int
   var numberOfPackets: Int
   var data: Data
}

func getDataFromPacket(packet: Packet) -> Data?{
  do{
    let data = try PropertyListEncoder.init().encode(packet)
    return data
  }catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
    return nil
}

func getPacketFromData(data: Data) -> Packet?{
    do{
      let packet = try PropertyListDecoder.init().decode(Packet.self, from: data)
      return packet
    }catch let error as NSError{
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used Jeff's example to create the following struct:

```
struct Series {
    
    var name: String?
    var season: String?
    var episode: String?
    
    init(name: String?, season: String?, episode: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.season = season
        self.episode = episode
    }
    
    static func archive(w: Series) -> Data {
        var fw = w
        return Data(bytes: &fw, count: MemoryLayout<Series>.stride)
    }
    
    static func unarchive(d: Data) -> Series {
        guard d.count == MemoryLayout<Series>.stride else {
            fatalError("Error!")
        }
        
        var w: Series?
        d.withUnsafeBytes({(bytes: UnsafePointer<Series>) -> Void in
            w = UnsafePointer<Series>(bytes).pointee
        })
        return w!
    }
}
```

Like Dag mentioned the whole thing is a bit fragile. Sometimes the App crashes when the name contains whitespace or an underline/underscore, and sometimes it crashes just without reason. In all cases the name which is unarchived looks similar to this '4\200a\256'. Surprisingly this is not a problem in the case of season or episode (like in "Season 2"). Here the whitespace doesn't force the app to crash.

Maybe it's an alternative to encode the strings to utf8 but I'm not familiar enough with the archive/unarchive methods to adapt them for this case.

Comment: This almost works for me. I create a few structs, swipe out the app, go back in and its there but if I swipe out again then tap back into the app, it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Max, I stopped working on this subject, because I read that with Swift 4 it will be much easier to convert structs (at least with strings) to NSData. For my project I decided to convert my Data with JSON into an asset and store this in iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this came out recently, and to me it is looking solid. Didn't try it yet...

https://github.com/a2/MessagePack.swift

---

Well, Swift doesn't have any magical serialization method, if that's what you are after. Since the good days of C, when you have a struct with a pointer, that is a flag that you can't serialize the bytes of that struct's instance without following the pointers and fetching their data. Same applies to Swift.

Depending on your Serialization needs and constraints, I'd say using `NSCoding` or even JSON strings will tidy your code and make it more predictable than the current state. Sure, you'll need to write a mapper, and there is an overhead. Everyone will tell you this: "Measure first".

**Now, here is the interesting part:**

If you **really** want to inline your data in that struct, and stream the contents without building the packet around `NSData` as you're doing, you can reserve bytes using Swift `Tuples`, which work much like how you would reserve bytes in C using `char[CONST]`:

```
struct what { 
    var x = 3 
}    

sizeof(what)

$R0: Int = 8

struct the { 
    var y = (3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 33) 
}    

sizeof(the)

$R1: Int = 56
```

To expand a bit on this, I think it's pretty horrible, but possible. You can write to the tuple's memory location and read from it [using something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29156687/456434).