# Saving Structs in Swift

Tags: swift, serialization, struct, nscoding, value-type

Having just watched a couple of videos on value types in Swift from WWDC this year,

[Building Better Apps With Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=414)
[Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408)

I'm finding myself fully ready to embrace value types in my apps. This means fewer Class types and more Structs. But how do I save this data? Previously, with Classes, I'd adopt NSCoding, but that requires that I adopt NSObject, which is going to require that I use a Class rather than a Struct.

Here are the options as I see them:

- If saving is necessary, the model is too complicated for a Struct and should be redesigned as a class
- [Design my own serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916535/swift-structs-to-nsdata-and-back)
- Use a mediator class

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the whole `NSCoding` business is intended and designed for storing/retrieving object trees.  Hence the requirement to have `NSObject` as a base class (perhaps at some point in future it might be moved to `AnyObject`, I guess).

Therefore, it is a responsibility of each class from such tree to encode/decode values of (some of) its properties, including structs.  All of these structs will be inevitably kept as a property of an object at some level, right?

Given the above, I think that the direction to explore would be to extend NSCoder protocol with functions like `encodeFoo(foo: Foo, forKey key: String)` and `decodeFooForKey(key: String) -> Foo`, where `Foo` would be one of your custom structs, and then use these functions in your classes that implement `NSCoding` protocol just the same way you would use similar functions for base Obj-C types.

Comment: Yeah, one of the built-in features of NSCoding is that it doesn't matter if you encode cycles — no matter what your object graph, `NSCoding` will encode each unique object in it only exactly once and not spin off into an infinite loop if you e.g. have a circular linked queue. That means that it is steeped within a world of reference semantics, over in Objective-C land. So giving it a value-or-reference-type makeover would probably be a bit of effort and hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Tommy, with objects it's possible to uniquely identify them by just the pointer.  With value-type instances, how is it possible to have them in cycle?  No irony, just trying to learn something new.

Comment: No, it's not possible to have a cycle with value semantics. All I meant was: the keyed archiver has a purely Objective-C world view and updating would be a hassle due to the semantic differences. So Apple hasn't, yet. I was agreeing with your first sentence about original intention and design, while speculating on why Apple hasn't moved on from the original design as of the time of writing.