# Persistent Storage of an Array of Structs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Array containing Structs.
I want to persistently store it.
Core Data is a bit complicated for my liking!
I've tried using an NSKeyedArchiver but It comes up with the error "cannot invoke achieve root object with an argument list of type ([Struct], toFile: String)

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916535/swift-structs-to-nsdata-and-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSKeyedArchiver / NSKeyedUnarchiver serializes serializes -compliant types to and from a data representation. So you will need to serialize your struct to persist.