# 'bytes' is unavailable: use withUnsafeBytes instead

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

Code that was previously working in Swift 2.2 is now throwing the following error in Swift 3:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let tempData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: 26)!
tempData.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, data.count), withBytes:data.bytes)
```

What should I replace "data.bytes" with to fix the error?  I've tried implementing 'withUnsafeBytes' and had a look at Apple's documentation, but can't get my head around it!

Comment: You haven't provided the source of `data`, but if you can convert that also to `Data`, this will all be much simpler and you won't need to bridge between `NSMutableData` and `Data`. You'll just use `replaceSubrange`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that `data` has type `Data`, the following should work:

```
let tempData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: 26)!
data.withUnsafeBytes { 
    tempData.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, data.count), withBytes: $0)
}
```

using the

```
/// Access the bytes in the data.
///
/// - warning: The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure.
public func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: @noescape (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

method of `Data`. Inside the closure `$0` is a `UnsafePointer<Void>`
to the bytes (`UnsafeRawPointer` in Xcode 8 beta 6).

Comment: @TejasArdeshna: That *is* Swift 3.

Comment: why length is hardcoded as 26? will it create any problem for large data? I am new to ios, just confirming.

Comment: @Ritchierich: The number 26 comes from the code in the question. There is no problem as long as your device has enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this
:**

```
        let data:Data = Data()
        let myDataBytes = data.withUnsafeBytes {_ in
            UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.withUnsafeBytes({
                $0
            }))
        }
        let writtenBytes = writeStream.write(.init(myDataBytes), maxLength: data.count)
```