# How split Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bytebuffer

I'm working on a project where I get a log back from an BLE device.

```
<37290000 00000000 0000>
```

This log contains the epochtime, a light value and a UV value. Now is my question, what is the best way to split this up?

I use the following code to get the above print:

```
print(data as NSData)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Split a String into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the log statement? Maybe you shouldn't be trying to get your values out of the log statement, but out of the original data.

Comment: @Marcel I updated the quesstion.

Comment: Do you want to split `bytes` or `Data`, or to do something with String `description` of `NSData`?

Comment: Maybe using a struct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916535/swift-structs-to-nsdata-and-back ?

Comment: @user28434 I want to split the Data, I have the rest of the code ready to continue after that.

Comment: Then you can use @Larme suggestion for bitmapping into structure. But also consider that `Data` is `Collection` and supports `subscript` with ranges, and enumerating over bytes (`UInt8`).

Comment: But *how* do you want to split it up? How many bits long is each piece? Is there padding? Is the data big endian or little endian? We cannot answer your question without knowing these details.