# How can I use an array of bytes to initialize a struct object in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, struct, bluetooth, byte

First, I am coming from a C programming background. My system consists of a device that is using software written in C language which utilizes Bluetooth to talk to the iPhone Application. I have a struct defined on the C device that I send byte by byte through Bluetooth and I am trying to reconstruct the struct in Swift.

In C, I would use a pointer to the array of bytes and simply typecast it to a pointer of my custom struct type:

```
uint8_t arrayOfBytes[16];

CustomStructType_t * structPtr = (CustomStructType_t *)arrayOfBytes;
```

In C, this is simple. I had an array of bytes, but I used typecasting to represent it as a custom struct instead.

Now on the iPhone, I capture the incoming Bluetooth bytes using Core Bluetooth. When a characteristic is updated, the following line accepts the bluetooth packet and converts it from Data type to String of bytes.

```
let incomingByteString = String(data: receivedBluetoothDataPacket, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

I'm honestly super lost at this point. I want to use this packet to initialize, or update the values of a struct object, lets say:

```
struct CustomStruct {
  let name: String!
  let value: Int
}
```

It would be nice if I could just tell Swift, Hey, I want you to create a CustomStruct object out of this incomingByteString.

Looks like this is going to be a real pain, and I may need to format the incoming packet much differently to accommodate Swift. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: From this 16 bytes, what range are `name: String` and `value: Int`? For example do you now that first 10 bytes is name and the rest is value or it's dynamic?

Comment: This probably will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916535/swift-structs-to-nsdata-and-back

Comment: @vpoltave You've already identified a key problem I need to resolve. The answer to your question is Yes, I do know precisely how many bytes are allocated for each member of the struct. However, the number of bytes allocated are defined on the C device. When it comes to swift I am not sure how to ensure that a struct member of type String is of size 10 bytes, for example. I need to be sure that in Swift, each member takes up a defined amount of bytes in memory, otherwise a simple byte pointer conversion would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = //get your bytes here
let customStruct = bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    ($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: CustomStruct.self, capacity: 1) { $0 })
}.pointee
```

You would have to convert your `receivedBluetoothDataPacket` to `[UInt8]` and you haven't provided the exact type.

Assuming it's `Data` a simple `[UInt8](receivedBluetoothDataPacket)` should suffice.

Comment: This is really helpful, but there appears to be a major problem if I wanted to include a String in the Struct. I know that the string would be a maximum of 16 bytes, but Swift does not appear to have a way of specifying strength length. So the block of memory that Swift creates for a struct does not seem to be contiguous and a simple byte copy using the starting address of the struct would fail.

Comment: I think your best shot would be 16 variables of `Int8` size and some struct method/computed property to finally yield it as a proper Swift `String`.